# is there a way to exclude displayName on GoogleSignIn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I don't want to retrieve the user name or profile photo that the user has on their Google Account.

```
export async function signUpGoogle() {
try {
    const result = await Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId: GOOGLE_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
        iosClientId: GOOGLE_IOS_CLIENT_ID,
        scopes: ["email"],
    });

    //console.log(result);

    if (result.type === "success") {
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(result.idToken);

        signInWithCredential(auth, credential).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
        console.log("cancelled");
    }
} catch (e) {
    return { error: true };
}}
```

The code I use for GoogleSignIn is above.

versions:

```
"expo": "~44.0.0",
"expo-google-app-auth": "~8.3.0",
"firebase": "^9.1.3",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.9.3",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sign in with Google, the result that you get contains all that information, the UID, the display name, the profile picture URL. There is no way to exclude those fields. If you don't want to use them, then simply ignore them.

However, if don't want to get user details, then you should consider implementing [Firebase Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth). In this way, you'll only have a UID, that can be only used to differentiate users. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
    const { user } = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    const user = {
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      displayName: user.displayName ?? 'User',
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
    };
```

Comment: sorry but it is not helping can you clarify your answer?